# How to override GWT-supplied implementation of CanvasElement in PlayN HTMLGraphicsCanvas?

Tags: gwt, playn

I'm looking to supply my own implementation of [CanvasElement](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/dom/client/CanvasElement.java) class. This class is instantiated in [HTMLGraphicsCanvas](http://code.google.com/p/playn/source/browse/html/src/playn/html/HtmlGraphicsCanvas.java) class in the PlayN stack.

What is the ideal way of doing this? There are 2 ways that I've tried but failed:

A) Subclassing HTMLGraphics and HTMLPlatform? --this doesn't seem to be possible.

B) The GWT module mechanism seems to require that my custom implementation of a GWT-supplied class be of the same package. So take for example this XML snippet:

```
<replace-with class="com.google.gwt.dom.client.DOMImplOpera">
    <when-type-is class="com.google.gwt.dom.client.DOMImpl"/>
    <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="opera"/>
</replace-with>
```

If I do something like:

```
<replace-with class="com.domain.example.CustomCanvasElement">
    <when-type-is class="com.google.gwt.dom.client.CanvasElement"/>
    <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="opera"/>
</replace-with>
```

...it does not seem to work because the packages are different. At least that's what I think is happening.

Any other ideas? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I can answer the B) part of my own question. Although I would really appreciate an answer to my overall question about how to supply my own implementation.

So my guess wasn't entirely correct. According to this section of [Deferred Binding](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred#example), basically you have to first create a superclass object that Browser-specific objects will subclass. So for instance:

`GenericBrowserObject` is the superclass and might have common implementations of certain methods between Browser-specific objects or might be your "catch-all" implementation for all other (non-specific) Browsers.

So for instance, let's say you only want to have specific implementations for IE and Gecko-based browsers.

`GeckoBrowserObject extends GenericBrowserObject`

`IEBrowserObject extends GenericBrowserObject`

Let's say that there is a common method called `setStyle` in `GenericBrowserObject` but they have differing implementations between `GeckoBrowserObject` and `IEBrowserObject`, then you would override `setStyle` in each of those classes and supply their own implementations.

The class that manipulates these objects needs to instantiate `GenericBrowserObject` superclass in this way:

```
    GenericBrowserObject obj = GWT.create(GenericBrowserObject.class);
    obj.setStyle("whatever");
```

Then in your module file (something.gwt.xml), you would have something like this:

```
    <replace-with class="com.domain.blah.GenericBrowserObject">
            <when-type-is class="com.domain.blah.GenericBrowserObject"/>
    </replace-with>

    <replace-with class="com.domain.blah.IEBrowserObject">
            <when-type-is class="com.domain.blah.GenericBrowserObject"/>
            <any>
                    <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="ie6"/>
                    <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="ie8"/>
            </any>
    </replace-with>

    <replace-with class="com.domain.blah.GeckoBrowserObject">
            <when-type-is class="com.domain.blah.GenericBrowserObject"/>
                    <any>
                            <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="gecko"/>
                            <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8"/>
                    </any>
    </replace-with>
```

When GWT compiles this, it will generate the correct objects based on the user agent string via GWT.create.